Is the set of all antichains of $\omega^{<\omega}$ avoiding all chains Borel?
Let's identify $\mathcal P(\mathbb N^{<\mathbb N})$ with $2^{\mathbb N^{<\mathbb N}}$, so it is a Polish space. The set $\mathcal A=\{A\subseteq \omega^{<\omega}: A \text{ is a maximal antichain}\}$ is easily seen to be Borel (where the order in question is the standard tree order of $\mathbb N^{<\mathbb N}$).
I am trying to decide whether $\{A\in\mathcal A: \forall g \in \omega^\omega\exists n \in \mathbb N\,g|n\in A\}$ is Borel. This is the set of maximal antichains that avoid all chains.
I can see it is coanalytic, as its complement is the projection of $F\subseteq \mathbb N^\mathbb N\times \mathcal A$ in the second coordinate, where $F=\{(g, A)\in \omega^\omega\times \mathcal A: \forall n \in \mathbb N\, g|n\notin A\}$ is easily seen to be Borel. Thus, it is Borel if and only if it is analytic.
Any help is appreciated.

It's a complete coanalytic set;.in  particular it's not analytic and therefore not Borel.

FYI, the antichains you are describing are often called "fronts" in the literature.

Let $\mathcal{A}'$ be the set of maximal antichains which meet every chain (you meant meet, not avoid, right?). Then  $\mathcal{A}'$ is complete coanalytic, and hence non-Borel. To prove this, I will give a Borel reduction from the set of well-founded trees (which is well-known to be complete coanalytic) to $\mathcal{A}'$.
Let $T$ be a tree (a non-empty downwards-closed subset of $\omega^{<\omega}$). First we modify $T$ to a tree $T'$ which is nowhere complete (i.e., such that for every node in $T'$, there is some node above it which is not in $T'$) and such that $T$ is well-founded if and only if $T'$ is, e.g., by padding the nodes in $T$ by zeros.
Now let $A(T)$ be the set of minimal elements of the complement of $T'$. $A(T)$ is clearly an antichain, and it is maximal: if $\eta$ is not in $T'$, there is some element of $A(T)$ below it, and if $\eta$ is in $T'$, then since $T'$ is nowhere complete, there is some element of $A(T)$ above it.
If $T'$ is well-founded, every chain contains an element not in $T'$, so $A(T)$ meets every chain. And if $T$ is not well-founded, $T'$ contains a chain, and $A(T)$ fails to meet this chain.
